# css for three images

Tags: css

I have three images within a `div` the problem is when I readjust the browser the images move and overlap.

http://jsfiddle.net/XZHzr/

I have tried several things, but am missing something within the css.  How do you get the images to stay fixed (in a row) in a web browser, but stack on each other if opened in a mobile browser or minimizing the browser?

Comment: FYI there is no such thing as `float:center;`

Comment: well thats good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example where images don't overlap and stack correctly if the browser window is readjusted to smaller width: http://jsfiddle.net/sGmjU/

I basically removed extra `div` tags around each image.

If you want to specifically control the behaviour in a desktop browser vs. mobile browser, then you should look into [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Answer (score 1):

you can just delete the width for each div, then it works well